# Change product image on variant change

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am struggling to find an ideal solution to change the product image based on the variant selection. I do not see any identifier on the product images using which I could do a cross matching for js change event.

Every theme has this feature, so I guess, there is a pretty good solution to this.

Can you please help me showing the right path?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the design of the page and what are using.

For example if you plan to show a single image for the variant change you can use the variant image directly.

But if you plan to use a gallery of images there are different approaches. The one I use in most cases is to set an ALT attribute to each image with the name of the color that it's pointing to. Based on those ALT attributes I use some JS logic to filter specific images and show the correct ones.

Other approaches will be to use metafields, tags, linklists etc... A lot of different ways, but each is tied to some JS logic and some bad user experience for the administration since he will be required to switch between different pages and to create different elements in order to tie them to the images.

The final way is to use a separate APP for this.

Comment: Every theme has this feature. Nobody is using an app for this. I was wondering if you know how to get the variant image! Can you please show me?

Comment: The variant image is just `variant.image`. The is the image ( single one ) beside each variant that you can uploiad